# What is the word to describe the set of correct answers to a test?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a multiple choice test the author of the test knows all the correct answers.

What is this set of correct answers called?

I have tried looking this up but I can't seem to find the word. The word in Norwegian is "fasit".

Comment: If it's just a list like "1:b, 2:c, 3:George Washington, 4:192" then it's normally called a "key".  Fasitnating,  no?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (a part of) [Exam-related vocabulary](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/447514/exam-related-vocabulary)

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate because the wording used to describe the word in that answer is completely different (I would not put those terms into google for example), and also it answers 4 questions not just one. That is my opinion anyway.

Comment: Surely the set of correct answers is merely called "the answers"!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just called an "**(answer) key**".

> [Key (Noun)](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/key#Noun):  A guide to the correct answers of a worksheet or
>   test.
>   *Some students cheated by using the answer key.*